# Question about client having office 2010 but 2007 office was used in development

Tags: .net, office-interop, .net-1.1

We have a .NET 1.1 application (please spare the why don't you upgrade, we can't right now).  We have references to the 2007 PIA's for development and if a client has 2007 installed our application works fine.  However if the client has 2010 installed when the run our export they get file not found Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  I have verified they have .NET support installed and the 2010 PIA's.  After some research I'm leaning towards that fact that perhaps we have to be on 2.0 in order for the PIA to work correctly.  Does any know how to solve the error or if I'm stuck because I'm still using .NET 1.1?  I am NOT using late binding but rather am referencing the Office.Interop DLL from .NET.  Would late binding solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it looks like you are, as the saying goes, SOL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx

Late binding could very well work, but you'd have to test it. If you do, just make sure to do it in a separate module!

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks.  It's 1.1 for now.  We will be upgrading to 4.0 early next year but are not in a position to at this point due to year end stuff.

Comment: From 1.1 to 4.0? Wow. The number of new things will be staggering. Got everyone trained yet?